# Overloading + operator in String class

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I have to implement a string class with operators [], +, +=, <<, >>, ==, !=, <, <=, >, >= but I cannot use the string object or include the  library for c++. Here is my code so far:

```
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class MyString {
public:
    MyString();
    MyString(const char* chars);
    int length() const;
    char * getValue()const;
    ~MyString();
    //copy constructor
    MyString(const MyString&);
    MyString& operator =(const MyString& s);
    char& operator[](int i);
    MyString& operator+=(const MyString& s);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const MyString&s);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&is, MyString&s);

    friend bool operator ==(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);
    friend bool operator <(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);

private:
    char* value;
    int size;
};
MyString operator+(const MyString s1, const MyString& s2);
bool operator !=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);
bool operator >=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);
bool operator <=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);
bool operator > (const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2);
//no arguments constructor
MyString::MyString() {
    value = 0;
    size = 0;
}
//constructor
MyString::MyString(const char* chars) {
    size = strlen(chars);
    value = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(value, chars);
}
int MyString::length()const {
    return size;
}
char* MyString::getValue()const {
    return value;
}
MyString::~MyString() {
    delete[] value;
}
//copy constructor
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s) {
    size = s.size;
    value = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(value, s.value);
}
MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString&s) {
    if (s.value == 0) {
        delete[] value;
        value = 0;
        size = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    if (this != &s) {
        delete[] value;
        value = new char[s.size + 1];
        strcpy(value, s.value);
        size = s.size;
    }
    return *this;
}
char& MyString::operator[](int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
        cout << "Please enter correct value of index" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

        return value[i];
    }
    return value[i];
}
MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& s) {
    char** temp = &value;
    *temp = new char[size];
    strcpy(value,*temp);
    strcat(value, s.getValue());

    if (size != 0) {
        delete[] temp;
    }
    size = strlen(value);
    return *this;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const MyString&s) {
    out << s.value;
    return out;
}
istream& operator >> (istream&in, MyString&s) {
    char*ptr = new char[100];
    in >> ptr;
    s = MyString(ptr);
    delete ptr;
    return in;
}
MyString operator+(const MyString s1, const MyString& s2) {
    MyString answer;
    answer += s1;
    answer+= s2;
    return answer;
}
bool operator ==(const MyString&s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return(strcmp(s1.value, s2.value) == 0);
}
bool operator<(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return (strcmp(s1.value, s2.value) < 0);
}
bool operator !=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return !(s1 == s2);
}
bool operator>(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return !(s1 == s2) && !(s1 < s2);
}
bool operator<=(const MyString& s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return s1 < s2 || s1 == s2;
}
bool operator >=(const MyString & s1, const MyString& s2) {
    return !(s1 < s2);
}
void test_copy_and_destructor(MyString S) {
    cout << "test: copy constructor and destructor calls: " << endl;
    MyString temp = S;
    cout << "temp inside function test_copy_and_destructor: " << temp << endl;
}

int main() {

    MyString st1("abc abc");
    MyString st2("9fgth");

    cout << "Copy constructor , << operator" << endl;

    MyString  st3(st1);

    cout << "st3: " << st3 << endl;

    test_copy_and_destructor(st2);

    MyString  st4;

    cout << "operator + " << endl;

    st4 = st3 + st2;

    cout << "st4: " << st4 << endl;

    cout << "st1 + st2: " << (st1 + st2) << endl;

    cout << "operators  [ ] " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < st2.length(); i++)
    cout << st2[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    cout << "operators  += , ==, != " << endl;

    st2 += st1;

    if (st3 == st1)
    cout << "st3 and st1 are identical " << endl;
    else cout << "st3 and st1 are not identical " << endl;

    if (st2 != st1)
    cout << "st2 and st1 are not identical " << endl;
    else cout << "st2 and st1 are identical " << endl;

    cout << "operators  < , <=, >, >= " << endl;

    if (st2 < st1)
    cout << "st2 < st1 " << endl;
    else cout << "st2 is not less than st1 " << endl;

    if (st1 <= st2)
    cout << "st1 <= st2 " << endl;
    else cout << "st1 is not less than or equal to st2 " << endl;

    if (st1 > st2)
    cout << "st1 > st2 " << endl;
    else cout << "not (st1 >  st2) " << endl;

    if (st1 >= st2)
    cout << "st1 >= st2 " << endl;
    else cout << "not (st1 >=  st2) " << endl;

    cout << "operator >> " << endl;

    //Open the data file
    ifstream  input("A9_input.txt");
    if (input.fail()) {
        cout << "unable to open input file A9_input.txt, Exiting..... ";
    return 0;
    }
    MyString temp1;
    MyString temp2("aaa");
    input >> temp1;
    input >> temp2;
    cout << "first element of input file: " << temp1 << endl;
    cout << "second element of input file: " << temp2 << endl;
    input.close();

    cout << "MyString says farewell....." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After reaching operator + my code reaches break point and crashes. I could tell something is wrong with my += operator code as + is using += code. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my += code?

Comment: Why is your assignment operator so complex?  It could simply  [look like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66ae1f05167a8c36).  And why are you allocating memory for `operator >>`?

Comment: Look at the first line of `operator+=`. Then the second. Then back at the first.

Comment: I have to assume that the string has MAX = 100 characters, each string is on a newline. That is there will not be more than one string on a line delimited by white space.

Comment: @Lucifellow *I have to assume that the string has MAX = 100 characters* -- That still doesn't explain why memory is allocated for `operator >>`.  You could have simply declared a `char ptr[100]`.

Comment: Also your `bool operator>` could be simply `{ return s2 < s1; }` .  The same thing can be said of operators  `>=` and `<=`.  You can figure out those two by using just `<` with no need for a compound statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `strcpy()` and `strcat()` to populate the *old* allocation, which is not large enough.  Therefore, the `strcat()` invocation attempts to write past the end of this allocation and the result is undefined behavior, which is manifesting as a crash on your system.

```
char* temp = value;
temp = new char[strlen(value) + s.length() +1];
strcpy(value, temp);  // <-- should be copying the other way
strcat(value, s.getValue()); // <-- should be copying into temp, not value
//if (size != 0) {
//  delete[]temp;
//}
size = strlen(value);
return *this;
```

Rewritten to solve this problem, as well as release the original string, and check for `value == nullptr`:

```
char *oldString = value == nullptr ? "" : value;

int newSize = strlen(oldString) + s.length();
char *newString = new char[newSize + 1];

strcpy(newString, oldString);
strcat(newString, s.getValue());

delete [] value;

value = newString;
size = newSize;

return *this;
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are trying to change what you pointer points to be using a pointer and not pointer to pointer.
when you are using the new operator your pointer simply gets new adress at the heap and than the assignment you did before(char * temp = value) is irelvent.
beacuse temp gets the adress pointed by value and not value adress, than any modification on temp adress will not effect value.
what you really wanna do is :

```
char * temp = new char[size]
//modify temp(add the strings)
//change value to hold the modified string
value = temp;
```

you can also do that :

```
char ** temp = &value;//now temp holds value's address.
*temp = new char[size];
//modify temp will modify value, but you need to derefrence before each use.
```

**update**

you are trying to copy a larger string temp into value which casues overflow (its a good practise to use strcpy_s/strcat_s beacuse they cannot copy more than the length you give them,  that should be the size of dest).

link to strcpy/strcpy_s doc : 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

what you should do is :

```
char * temp = new char[size];
//strcpy_s(dest, length of dest, src)
strcpy_s(temp , sizeof temp, value);//copy value to temp
strcat_s(temp, sizeof temp, s.getValue());
if(value != nullptr)
  delete [] value;
value = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this was really useful in clearing concepts about memory management .